# The second to the last line of code is confusing to me

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I am quite new to python and programming in general so I am still trying to understand the details in practice. This is a problem I found online so I can practice nested loops more. If my question is missing anything or you do not understand my question, please let me know. I would like to get better at asking good questions as well.

```
list =[[1, 2], [3,4]]
m = 1
print(list)
for i in range(0, 2):
    m *= 10
    for j in range(0, 2):
        list[i][j] *= m  # This part right here.
print(list)
```

This is what prints on the terminal:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[10, 20], [300, 400]]
```

I was trying to go through this block of code step by step to make sure I understand it but this part is stumping me. I understand that the whole function of this nested for loop is to multiply the items in the 1st list with 10 and the 2nd list with 100. I also know what the `*= m` part is, the part that's confusing to me is the code right before that on the same line.

So far I tried to just copy this specific part in google and see if anything came up. I could not find anything that would make sense. I also tried to just run this whole line and see what printed (`list[i][j] *= m`)(I changed the variable to numbers obviously). That only came up with a type error... There are no type variables left in `list[2]`. I was trying to isolate it to see what just this part does but it apparently doesn't work like that. I guess i need to think outside the box a little more maybe.

Comment: For some reason i entered the code as its typed, like in the correct format with the indents and everything. But it posted it more like a sentence. Im not sure why it did that :(..

Comment: If you were using the Stacks Editor, it has problems.

Comment: Don't use the name of built in things like `list` as variable names....

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback and help. All very helpful.

Comment: This is just a random question that i cant seem to remember long term so if it gets answered here then i at least have it written down. How do you comment out a whole block of code at once? So, instead of going to each line and adding a #, which is time consuming and annoying. I have seen it been done but googling it doesnt seem to bring up the answer. Thanks to anyone.

Comment: Please make sure to accept an answer if it helped you. (To answer your off-topic question:  start and end block comment with three quotation marks `"""comment"""`)

Answer (score 0):

If we take i to be 1 and j to be 1, list[i][j] would be 4. list[i] = [3,4] so what you're doing is finding index 1 of the list [3, 4]

Comment: Ok so it looks like i just forgot what the format or setup was for getting and index. I didnt recognize it at first. Especially since there was 2 instances where its checking for an index. I didn't know you could do that, I would have thought it would need to be list[i] *= m and then a seperate one for list[j] *= m.

Answer (score 0):

`list = [[1,2], [3,4]]` is an array of arrays.
To get a single element, you have to subscript `list` twice, which is exactly what `list[i][j]` is.

`list[0]` returns `[1,2]`, the 0-th element of the list, which is a sublist

`list[0][0]` returns `1`, the 0-th element of the 0-th sublist

`list[0][1]` returns `2`, the 1st element of the 0-th sublist

.

`list[1]` returns `[3,4]`, the 1st element of the list, which is a sublist

`list[1][0]` returns `3`, the 0-th element of the 1st sublist

`list[1][1]` returns `4`, the 1st element of the 1st sublist

.

Also, the reason why `list[2]` doesn't return anything is because `list` only has two elements, which have the index `0` and `1`, so trying to get the element at index `2` will not work

Answer (score 0):

`list` is a list containing nested lists.

`list[0]` is the list `[1, 2]`. `list[1]` is the list `[3, 4]`.

When you use two indexes like `list[i][j]`, it first gets the nested list `list[i]`, then accesses the `[j]` element of that. So when `i == 0` and `j == 1`, this accesses the list element containing `2`.

`*= m` then multiplies that list element. So when `i == 0` and `m == 10`, it multiplies the values in the first sublist by 10. Then when `i == 1` and `m == 100` it multiplies the values in the second sublist by 100.